# Create Swagger Model from Class

Tags: java, swagger

I'm working on documenting an API made with RESTeasy + Jackson in Java using Swagger/OpenAPI (jars are version swagger-[]-1.5.18.jar). I have an endpoint that can take in one of several objects as Strings. I found a way to add models using Swagger's `ReaderListener`; however, I want it to be able to generate the `Model`s automatically since they are still in flux. I found that I can use `ModelConverters` to generate the `Schema`s from a class; however, I have been unable to find a way to easily generate `Model` `Property`s from these `Schema`s. I did find this [example](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/7cad47dd399f149a50e028bffc41b6a886b3f96e/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/java/io/swagger/codegen/InlineModelResolver.java#L47), but it involves adding a lot of extra code.

Are there any functions that will do so and get all of the inner `Schema`s? Or is there a better way to go from a `Class` to a `Model`?

Here is my current code:

```
@SwaggerDefinition
public class SwaggerModelDefinitionAdder implements ReaderListener {
    @Override
    public void afterScan(Reader arg0, Swagger swagger) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeScan(Reader arg0, Swagger swagger) {  
        ModelConverters mc = new ModelConverters();
        Map<String, Schema> class1Schemas = mc.read(Class1.class);
        Map<String, Schema> class2Schemas = mc.read(Class2[].class);

        final Model class1Model = new ModelImpl()
                .name("Class1")
                .type("Class1");
        class1Model.setReference("#/definitions/Class1");

        final Model class2Model = new ModelImpl()
                .name("Class2")
                .type("Class2");
        class2Model.setReference("#/definitions/Class2");

        Map<String, Model> definitions = new HashMap<>();
        definitions.put("Class1", class1Model);
        definitions.put("Class2", class2Model);
        swagger.setDefinitions(definitions);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there something preventing you from upgrading? In Swagger2 this "just works" since (as far as I know) it just uses reflection to read all the model fields and add them automatically.

Comment: @Hitobat I can double check on upgrading; would you mind clarifying what you mean by "just works"? Adding the models in the `ReaderListener` as above without the `ModelConverters`?

Comment: @Hitobat there is nothing preventing upgrading; however, 1.5.19 is the newest version of most of the jars on Maven without going to v3 OAS.